# Align All Div Children to Bottom Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align all div's children to its bottom. I used `dispalay:table and table-cell` method(that I found on net), but that is not working for me. I also tried some other methods too, but could not get it done. Here is [LINK](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/RNzjOg) and my code structure:

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="al" style="background:green;"></div>
    <div class="al" style="background:blue;"></div>
    <div class="al" style="background:tan;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a{
  float: left;
  background: red;
  display: table;
  padding-right: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}
.b{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 29px;
}
.c{
  height: 300px;
  width: 90px;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
}
.al{
  margin-top: 2px;
  background: yellow;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Here is the [Link of Code](http://codepen.io/iiison/pen/RNzjOg)

Comment: Is the desired result essentially what you have now, just with the green, blue, and tan divs at the bottom?

Comment: yes, they should be in aligned vertically and should start from bottom

Comment: @Oriol `.al` is already 100%, see 27th line of CSS code.

Comment: @j08691 I am not sure How to get an Image, but all `.al` should be vertically aligned instead of horizontal and they should cover full width of their parent.

Comment: @Oriol there will be one element in a row, and aligned vertically. See the result of this http://jsbin.com/zifazidaqu/1/edit, I want the output same as that.

Comment: @j08691 please see the output of this: http://jsbin.com/zifazidaqu/1/edit. I need same as that. I tried to follow this, but could not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align the contents of `.b` to the bottom, you can use

```css
.b {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Full code:

```css
.a {
  display: table;
  padding-right: 1px;
  background: red;
}
.b {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 29px;
  background: blue;
}
.c {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 300px;
  width: 90px;
  background: grey;
}
.al {
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="b">
    <div class="al" style="background:green;"></div>
    <div class="al" style="background:blue;"></div>
    <div class="al" style="background:tan;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```